# No results when searching with special characters in custom metadata property

Tags: search, user-profile-service, search-results, user-profile-property, metadata

We have an issue with SharePoint 2010 Search. Currently, we have a property in Active Directory, for each user, that specify their initials. We have a scheduled task that runs every hour to sync these Active Directory properties with our custom user profile property for "Initials". We have created a metadata property in SharePoint Search called "Initials" that maps to "People:Initials(Text)".

Now, we're able to search for initials and get results for the user who have that initial. It works perfectly, except that it doesn't like special characters. In other words, if your initials start with Æ, Ø or Å, either no results get shown or results for "O" is shown when searched for "Ø", and "A" is shown when searched for "Å".

Have anyone ever seen an issue like this and/or know how I can solve this issue?

If you need any more details to answer this question, leave a comment.

Comment: It's a common language "bug" for SharePoint with Scandinavian characters. Make sure the correct language package is installed in order for the system to read the letters. If that doesn't help, try converting Æ to AE, Ø to OE, Å to AA.